# What programming language would be most beneficial to have the most proficiency with?

Tags: programming-languages

I still have a lot to learn in terms of programming and currently only know a decent amount of C++.  I'm aware that different languages have different uses, but I was just wondering if there was perhaps one that stood out as a superior language or a language that would be applicable to more tasks?

Thanks

Comment: Sam, I see you haven't selected an answer for any of your previous questions. You select an answer by clicking the check mark underneath each person's "rating" that is on the left side of their answer. It will turn green once you click it.

Comment: Star working with c++ is cool, you should carry on!

Comment: @Briz, yeah sorry, I was in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is really big in today's world, since almost everything on the internet uses it. You'll find Java will be a major part of a lot of different apps.

In the work world however, I believe C# is the most common language that companies are using. Almost all of the job notifications my computer science advisor sends out are asking for people experienced with C#. My boyfriend is currently working at a company that writes programs for casinos, and they use C#.

C++ is still a pretty major language though. It's what *my* job mainly uses.

Answer (score 0):

No not really. All languages have different uses and work on different platforms. Generally most OOp languages are similar in logic and only vary in syntax. Just get stuck in and you'll eventually be able to adapt to whatever language you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

Every language has its own set of prons, but mostly languages have same coding rules. Its better to have knowledge of multiple languages so, that you can choose which is perfect for your project, like I prefer c# for desktop application development and PHP for web applications so In the end you should be master of one. Mostly developers starts with C++ which is perfect for amateurs.

Top 5 Languages

1. Java popularity: 18.482% +1.13%
2. C popularity: 14.986% -1.62%
3. C++ popularity: 8.187% -1.26%
4. Python popularity: 7.038% +2.72%
5. PHP popularity: 6.973% -3.03%

This what I found but not sure its correct.

Best :)
Waqar Alamgir

Comment: I would of expected C# in the top five. Interesting.

Comment: @townsean Of course, the submitter did say that he doesn't validate these percentages. They aren't necessarily correct.

Comment: Yes c# on 6th, but for 2011 the popular languages will be Python and C# :(